# Debounce event/command in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, caliburn.micro

I am in the process of building a universal windows application using Caliburn.Micro, unfortunately due to certain hardware limitations we are needing to target Windows 10 1607 so cannot implement any packages with dependencies on .NET Standard / UWP 16299, this includes ReactiveUI.

In this particular scenario, I have a view-model first approach which generates a map (and some other resources), these are then bound to a mapview in the XAML view. Ideally, I want to trigger a process when the map is moved via the `ViewpointChanged` event.

**View Model**

```
public class ExampleViewModel : Screen
{
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        Map = new Map();
    }

    public Map Map { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<MapItems> MapItems { get; set; }

    private UpdateMapItems(Envelope visibleArea)
    {
        // The visibleArea param will include the current viewpoint of the map view
        // This method will effectively generate the appropriate map items based on the current coordinates
    }
}
```

**View**

```
...
<MapView x:Name="MapView" Map="{Binding Map}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event ViewpointChanged] = [Action UpdateMapItems(MapView.VisibleArea.Extent)]" />
...
```

Now this *technically* works but has a major flaw in that each movement of the map fires the ViewpointChanged event several times (similar effect to that of OnMouseMove for example).

Ideally I'd like to be able to throttle/debounce this event so that the map items are only processed when the view hasn't been moved for say 300ms.

I found an article that involved implementing a `DispatcherTimer` however elements of this code such as the `DispatcherPriority` and `Dispatcher` don't seem to be available in UWP so unless alternatives exist, I don't think this will work.

I have had a look at System.Reactive but this seemed exceptionally complicated for what I'm looking to achieve.

Any pointers would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have a look a [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) and the example right on that page (top right)

Comment: Unfortunately ReactiveUI has a dependency on UWP 10.0.16299 which we are unable to meet as the application needs to run on devices with 10.0.14393 (LTSB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a couple of ways.

1. Reactive Extensions

The desired behavior can be achieved using the `Throttle` operator.

```cs
Observable
.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(MapView, nameof(ViewpointChanged));
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(300));
.Subscribe(eventPattern => vm.UpdateMapItems(eventPattern.Sender.VisibleArea.Extent));
```

When using `FromEventPattern` we're mapping events to instances of [EventPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229009%28v%3dvs.103%29), which includes the `Sender` (source) of the event.

I tested by subscribing to a `UIElement`'s `PointerMoved` event. Which triggers `HandleEvent` multiple times if we keep moving. With `Throttle`, however, the event handler is executed only once. This is when the interval has passed *after* we stop moving.

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="..."
    ...
    >
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="MyUIElement" Content="Throttle Surface"
                Height="250" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Observable
            .FromEventPattern<PointerRoutedEventArgs>(MyUIElement, nameof(UIElement.PointerMoved))
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
            .Subscribe(eventPattern => HandleEvent(eventPattern.Sender, eventPattern.EventArgs));
    }

    private void HandleEvent(object source, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Pointer Moved");
    }
}
```

2. Something custom

Our custom `Throttle` class keeps track of the last `sender` and `args` that have been processed. Processed as in "passed to `Throttle` for processing". Only when the timer elapses, and no other events have occurred, is the `eventHandler` (passed as a constructor argument) actually executed.

```cs
public class Throttle<TEventArgs>
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private object _lastSender;
    private TEventArgs _lastEventArgs;

    public Throttle(EventHandler<TEventArgs> eventHandler, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = interval
        };
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            eventHandler(_lastSender, _lastEventArgs);
        };
    }

    public void ProcessEvent(object sender, TEventArgs args)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Start();

        _lastSender = sender;
        _lastEventArgs = args;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly Throttle<PointerRoutedEventArgs> _throttle;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        _throttle = new Throttle<PointerRoutedEventArgs>(HandleEvent, interval);
        MyUIElement.PointerMoved += (sender, e) => _throttle.ProcessEvent(sender, e);
    }

    private void HandleEvent(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Pointer Moved");
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

> I'm struggling to work out how everything fits together in an MVVM environment. The logic that needs to be triggered by the event is contained within the ViewModel but the View and ViewModel should be entirely separate.

There's a couple things I'd like to mention:

- You're right about the need for separation of concerns, but a lot of devs are unclear of what that exactly entails. The view model should be completely unaware of who's listening, there's no doubt about that. But the view is dependent on the view model to get its data, so it's okay for the view to know about the view model. The problem is more about doing so in a loosely coupled way, ie. using bindings and contracts instead of directly accessing view model members.
- That's why I'm not particularly fond of Caliburn's Actions. With `cal:Message.Attach` there's no contract (eg. ICommand) to decouple view syntax from the view model's. Of course, there are bindings in play, so you still get decoupled MVVM layers.

Long story short, there's a reason people choose ReactiveUI over Rx.NET for WPF development.
From the view's code behind (_.xaml.cs) it gives you access to:

- The backing `ViewModel`
- A binding system to keep it all loosely coupled

And, of course, `ReactiveCommands`, which would also come in handy in your use case.

Final thoughts, if your view has the same lifetime as your view model (ie. they get disposed together), you could be pragmatic about it and get the view model through the `DataContext` of your view.

Comment: Thanks for that! The Reactive approach is almost perfect but I'm struggling to work out how everything fits together in an MVVM environment. The logic that needs to be triggered by the event is contained within the ViewModel but the View and ViewModel should be entirely separate.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. ReactiveUI comes up a lot, unfortunately the 1607 build requirement means I cant use it for this project. I did think about another approach which involves using CM's message.attach to trigger a property setter in the ViewModel and then observing the property with a throttle to trigger a method that way, not sure if that would be a better approach in this scenario.